# Format NSNumber as __ k/M/B

Tags: ios, nsstring, formatting, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am working on an app and I want to format a number such as 1,000,000 as a short string.

Some examples would be:

```
1000 => "1k"
50000 => "50k"
83952 => "84k"
1000000 => "1m"
1000000000 => "1b"
```

I was thinking the best way to do this would be using a [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter) or just rounding it then counting the number of "0"'s.  Anyone have an example of using a NSNumberFormatter in this manner or any resources to get started.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. It's not referring to file size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the NSNumberFormatter:

Example:

```
@implementation LTNumberFormatter

@synthesize abbreviationForThousands;
@synthesize abbreviationForMillions;
@synthesize abbreviationForBillions;

-(NSString*)stringFromNumber:(NSNumber*)number
{
if ( ! ( abbreviationForThousands || abbreviationForMillions || abbreviationForBillions ) )
{
    return [super stringFromNumber:number];
}

double d = [number doubleValue];
if ( abbreviationForBillions && d > 1000000000 )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [super stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d / 1000000000]], abbreviationForBillions];
}
if ( abbreviationForMillions && d > 1000000 )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [super stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d / 1000000]], abbreviationForMillions];
}
if ( abbreviationForThousands && d > 1000 )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [super stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d / 1000]], abbreviationForThousands];
}
    return [super stringFromNumber:number];
}

@end
```